# C# asp.net: error - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, database, adapter

Here is the code for the database layer function:

```
    public static dsPersonnel GetPersonnel(string Database, string strSearch)
    {
        dsPersonnel DS;
        OleDbConnection sqlConn;
        OleDbDataAdapter sqlDA;

        //create the connection string
        sqlConn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Database);

        string query;
        if (strSearch == "" || strSearch.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            query = "SELECT * from tblPersonnel";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = " + strSearch + "";
        }




        //create the adapter with query
        sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);

        //create the dataset
        DS = new dsPersonnel();

        //fill the data set
        sqlDA.Fill(DS.tblPersonnel);

        //return the dataset
        return DS;
    }
}
```

if the postback submits a blank string, i have it return all records. but when a real string is passed to the function, i get the error "no value given for one or more required parameters". for the line

```
sqlDA.Fill(DS.tblPersonnel);
```

In debug, I verified that the string is building correctly for both cases, but i get the error with the latter. **I understand that I should be using parameterized queries**, but this is the step in the learning process in class that I am on. One problem at a time :). Any suggestions on what the issue here is?

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = 
     "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = '" + 
      strSearch + 
      "'";
```

Add quotes around the search criteria

Comment: i found it almost as soon as i posted this lol. thanks guys. will pick first answer once timer is up.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = '" + strSearch + "'";
```

or better

```
query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = '{0}'", strSearch);
```

Comment: @Oded - That's not a parameterized query, and has all the same security problems as using concatenation.  The only difference is that it might be slightly more efficient.  string.Format will happily let you insert a sql injection.

Comment: @Mystere Man - My bad. I saw the format and assumed it was parameterized.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enclose strings in single quotes in SQL.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = '" + strSearch + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you're quoting the parameter you're passing in to your query.

Instead of

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = " + strSearch + "";
```

try

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tblPersonnel WHERE LastName = '" + strSearch.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

Notice the extra single quotes, and also the Replace() statement which correctly escapes single quotes contained in your filter (e.g. apostrophes)

Must reiterate that your sample code does contain multiple problems and security vulnerabilities.